# AsyncTask in Android - UI blocking during audio recording

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've searched a lot, and I'm not able to find a solution to this problem. I'm creating an app that processes audio real-time. So, I've created an ASyncTask that initializes the microphone and processes the sound received:

```
public class SoundSampler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

AudioRecord recorder;
int bufferSize;
final short[] audioData;

public SoundSampler() {
    int samplerate = 44100;
    int encoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplerate, config, encoding);
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, samplerate, config, encoding, bufferSize);

    final int finalBufferSize = bufferSize;
    audioData = new short[finalBufferSize];             

    OnRecordPositionUpdateListener positionUpdater = new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
        // do something amazing with audio data (long operations)
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {                            Log.d("Process", "marker reached");
        }
    };
    recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(positionUpdater);
    recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(64);
    Log.d("Process", "starTAGt recording, bufferSize: " + bufferSize);
    Log.d("Process", "state = " + recorder.getState() + " aud = " + audioData.length);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        recorder.startRecording();
        Log.d("Process", "rec = " + recorder.getRecordingState());
        while (!isCancelled()) {
             recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        recorder.stop();
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is my main activity's onCreate:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button on = (Button) findViewById(R.id.on);
        Button off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.off);

        final SoundSampler smp =  new SoundSampler();

        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 smp.execute();
            }
        });

        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                smp.cancel(true);
            }
        });


    }
```

Now, sound is registered, but after I start the SoundSampler AsyncTask the Ui gets blocked. I want SoundSampler to register data, but I want him to stop as I want from the main UI. Have you some suggestions on about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` methods are being called on the UI thread. You can confirm this by inserting the following log statement within the listener's methods:

```
Log.i(TAG, "OnRecordPositionUpdateListener on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

You'll have to spawn a new thread to perform your long-running operations within `onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder){}`